# How to set a:visited and a:hover programmatically in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, hover

Can someone tell me how to set `a:visited` and `a:hover` programmatically? I am dynamically building up some hyperlinks server-side and want to know how to specify unique css behaviour for each link. Otherwise I would set them all in a stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the style for a single item, you can use the `CssClass` attribute, then set up the classes in your css.

```
.linkA:visited {
    color: red;
}
.linkB:visited {
    color: blue;
}
```

In your codebehind:

```
LinkOne.CssClass = "linkA";
LinkTwo.CssClass = "linkB";
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure I understand - wouldnt this work?

Hyperlink1.CssClass = MyAnchorClass;

Answer (score 1):

Unless things have changed, you can't specify the a:visited and a:hover within an HTML anchor (a) tag, so in the end you will need CSS somewhere (on the page, in a file) and assign the class to each anchor tag, like what willoller said.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it inside code:

```
imageButton.Attributes.Add("onmouseout",
    "this.src='../../../App_Themes/White/Images/default.png';");
imageButton.Attributes.Add("onmouseover",
    "this.src='../../../App_Themes/White/Images/default.hover.png';");
imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/White/Images/default.png";
```